# How to jump the infinite while loop when all data read out of the pipe?

Tags: bash, pipe

```
cat  pipe.sh
#！/bin/bash
fifo_file=fifo.pipe
mkfifo $fifo_file
exec 6<>$fifo_file
rm $fifo_file

DateWrite ()
{
    i=0
    while [ $i -lt 100 ]
    do
        str=`date`
        i=$(( i+1 ))
        echo "$i $str"
    done
}

for  (( i=0; i<10; i++ ))
do 
     ( DateWrite >&6 ) &
done
while read date_time
do
    echo $date_time >> output.file
done <&6
```

The above bash code create a named pipe,`DateWrite` function write a string in pipe,it create a 10 process with for loop ,read data from pipe with while loop.
`bash pipe.sh` can't stop,it enter into a infinite while loop.
How to jump the while loop when all data read out of the pipe?
Another issue:Why `rm $fifo_file` after `exec 6<>$fifo_file`?

Try as @chepner say:

```
vim pipe.sh
#！/bin/bash
fifo_file=fifo.pipe
mkfifo $fifo_file
exec 6<>$fifo_file
rm $fifo_file

DateWrite ()
{
    i=0
    while [ $i -lt 100 ]
    do
        str=`date`
        i=$(( i+1 ))
        echo "$i $str"
    done
}

writers=()
for  (( i=0; i<10; i++ ))
do 
     ( DateWrite >&6 ) & writers+=($!)
done

while read date_time
do
    echo $date_time >> output.file
done <&6 &

for writer in "${writers[@]}"; do
  wait "$writer"
done

exec 6>&-
```

It works fine.
There are two lines here i don't understand.

```
writers=()
 ( DateWrite >&6 ) & writers+=($!)
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while loop will try to read from the pipe as long as it is open for writing. Once all the writers have completed, you can close the pipe explicitly.

```
fifo_file=fifo.pipe
mkfifo $fifo_file
exec 6<>$fifo_file
rm $fifo_file

writers=()
for  (( i=0; i<10; i++ ))
do 
     ( DateWrite >&6 ) & writers+=($!)
done

while read date_time
do
    echo $date_time >> output.file
done <&6 &

for writer in "${writers[@]}"; do
  wait "$writer"
done

exec 6>&-
```

Comment: I have tried wit the method,failed.,please check it .

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to check. This code works for me.

Comment: Please see my update,there are two lines i don't understand,would you mind explaining it?

Comment: They are collecting the process ids of the background writers in an array, so that you know which processes to wait on later.